# Input tag within div elements provided Google Maps API not taking POST

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, google-maps-api-3

The below code of input tags within the div tag provided by Google Maps API helps to set the directions between 2 points of the user input.

We are trying to take this input using a POST request by placing it within a form in a NODE server using express.

What we noticed is that the first 2 input tags without any associated id or class allow us to send a POST request to our node server and pick it with body-parser.

But the next 2 input tags provided by Google containing the respective id and class is not sending any text over POST request.

The question is how to override this behavior?

```
<form class="" action="/users/<%= name %>/orderplace" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="hrishi" value="">
  <input type="text" name="jatin" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Place Order</button>
<h1>Hi <%= name %> enter your order location </h1>


  <div style="display: none">



    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location" name="fromlocation">

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location" name="tolocation">



</div>
</form>
```

Comment: because it doesn't have any values. you need to first fill the input field before submit

Comment: We are getting values for these fields from Google's auto-complete @TajKhan